# Getting PostgreSQL Query Error with PHP and Sessions

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

The problem I encountered has to do with the query using session variables.

during the user login i assigned a session variable as such

```
$myemail = $_POST['email'];
$mypassword = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$myemail'";
$result = pg_query($db,$sql);
$row = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if(count($result) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
}
```

The highlight is `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id']`

Next once the user logs in i want to find the info of the user in my database, so I searched for the user as such

```
$userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$result = pg_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$userid'") or die("error on query");

$user_info = pg_fetch_assoc($result);
```

But I keep on getting `error on query` showing that the query is failing. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: check for the real error maybe? there are methods at your disposal for this.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the funny thing is that if i replace the line by say id = 2, it actually works, so the error must be related to the session variable

Comment: did that answer solve it below?

Comment: if user id is int in your db you don't need the single ticks('').  This will cause query failure as well. You could try something like this  ".$userid."

Comment: you now have 3 answers

Comment: you're not saying a word here about the answers given. Or, have you left for somewhere or you're trying to debug this? I have a few ideas but as I said earlier, you need to check for the real errors. You can ping me back if you want but I have to leave the post now. Good luck

Comment: sorry, was busy debugging. I have found that Jonny's answer actually worked! so sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if user id is int in your db you don't need the single ticks(''). This will cause query failure as well. You could try something like this ".$userid."

```
$result = pg_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$userid."") or die("error on query");
```

Answer (score 0):

but count($result) won't give you row count. Try using

```
if(pg_num_rows($result) == 1){
 $session['user_id']= $row['id'];
}else{
echo pg_num_rows($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Underneath $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id']; in the same if statement, echo the id to see what response you get

```
echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Comment: this isnt an answer its should be a comment

Comment: I can't comment, my reputation isn't high enough.

Comment: fair enough i guess.